# ASP:Hyperlink throwing a postback in Firefox, but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Confusingly, or perhaps not, I don't want it to postback, as it is loading a popup containing content, but the postback closes the popup.

The code is really simple, and its just a bog standard `asp:Hyperlink`. Theres nothing that I can see which could cause this, and I am mainly confused as to how and why it is being handled so differently by each browser.

The only thing I could think of was JS with

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Any one got any ideas what could cause this?

I am reloading an iFrame with a new source, which sits on the page, but it is forcing the entire page to postback on firefox only.

```
iFrame.attr('src', newSrc);
```

The rest of the code:

```
$('.button-try-glasses').on('click', function (event) {
    var modal = $('#modal-container');
    var newAsset = $(this).attr('data-asset');
    var iFrame = modal.find('iframe');
    var currentIFrameSrc = iFrame.attr('src');

    var newSrc = currentIFrameSrc.substring(0, (currentIFrameSrc.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)) + newAsset;

    iFrame.attr('src', newSrc);
    Trylive.parse();
    showPopup($(null), '#modal-container', true);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

If I comment out the `.attr` line, it doesn't update the source, but it also doesn't postback and then close the component.

Comment: can you show full js code what you are doing?

Comment: Can you post your HTML and full js code or create fiddle .

Answer (score 0):

To answer exactly we need your aspx and js code. For quick hit and try. There must be some Js error. You can write

```
return false;
```

at the end of your Js code.

Comment: It's not reaching the end of the code. It's getting to the line iFrame.attr('src', newSrc); and then it is starting a postback. It doesn't get beyond that line.

Comment: If your link is also in other iframe then this line set its src to new location that will results in postback. So try to get your desired frame by id.

Comment: There is only one iframe which is affected. But it is still causing a postback, and only in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

As the others mentioned we need your aspx and js code.

But as a workaround you can try to wrap your **ifram** with asp **UpdatePanel** which should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.button-try-glasses').on('click', function (event) {
event.preventDefault(); //put it here
....

 return false; //this must be last line 
});
```

hope that works for you

Comment: It isn't getting as far as that in the code. It is starting a postback on the line iFrame.attr('src', newSrc);

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with the page you are trying to load in the iframe. The javascript in the iframe could be doing something like top.location = "post url" or window.parent.location="post url".

Could you try opening another url like google.com in your iframe and see if the problem persists

iFrame.attr('src', "http://google.com");

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try checking the following options for errors -

1. Order of calling => It is always a better approach to call loading or contents of your modals after the modal is shown. Because until the containers of modals are shown, you might not be able to use them in codes. For example, calling `iFrame.attr('src', newSrc);` after executing `showPopup($(null), '#modal-container', true);` could be a good idea.
2. Check Url => Make sure url is properly generated and the url you are trying to load supprts CORS.

I have tested with `Twitter Bootstrap` to try to load an `iframe` inside a modal, it worked perfectly. You might wanna check out the codes at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88xprqft/7/), this might help you solving yours.

Here is a screenshot of the content loaded in modal - 
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for this.
I have played around with the jsfiddle, and found out that if I remove the initial iframe src declared in the html then it will not postback. Could you shed any light on why this might be?